# Forward remote connection request to a destination computer (optional using Thrift framework)

Tags: c#, .net-core, thrift, windows-10-iot-core

We are doing feasibility study on following requirement "Forward the remote connection request to another computer (optional using Thrift framework)".

for example,  let say machine 1 being listening to remote connection request, received a remote connection request, machine 1 forward the request to machine 2. The server installed on both of them is VNC.

My current theoretical design goes like below,
Machine 1 listening to remote connection request, when ever a remote connection request comes, using thrift framework machine 1 will forward the request to machine 2. Machine 2 now send the response to machine 1, machine 1 will respond to its requester.

There is no technical solution yet, doing the feasibility study. For the theory mentioned above ,my first question is, is it technically feasible?

Is there any other alternate solution available other than thrift framework. (No third party software's).

Please note that the OS which we are working on is Windows 10 IOT core.

Please let me know your thoughts, which achieves the primary goal on Windows 10 IOT core.

Thanks

Comment: Theoretically, Your design inclines towards Machine1 acting as a proxy. If you have control over the connection layer of client and server both, why not Machine1 (checks which machine is the relevant one) and responds with reconnect advice to Requester providing details about where to connect next.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava machine 2 is not accessible to client. Client knows only about machine 1.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy  Your study is more like a reverse proxy then.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a WCF service or [App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) as a proxy service in UWP app which run on Windows IoT Core. I'm not sure how you will implement the remote client to connect the machine 1. If the client is an UWP app also, it is easy to call the App Service. If the client if WinForm, you need to create a bridge to access the App Service. Please refer to the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AppServiceBridgeSample) here.

This [article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36719.wcf-app-services-in-universal-windows-platform-uwp-using-windows-10.aspx) shows the different ways (WCF & App Services) in UWP which can run on Windows IoT Core.

Comment: The connections are via VNC client  and server, so we need to design a proxy which just communicate back and forth.

Comment: @Srikanth, please have a read this topic which discussed how to set proxy on Windows IoT Core.